# How to make google address autofill using API, to replace full address with number & street?

Tags: javascript, html, api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using a google API to auto-fill an address form. Right now i found code to fill out the full address, which auto-populates all of the fields in picture link #1 as shown. I have hidden the street number and route fields as they are not needed.

What i am looking for, is after i select the address, i want the address bar i was typing in to not display the city, state and country in that field bar. I want the auto-fill to look like what is shown in picture link #2, where the address field replaces the full address with only the number and street, and does not include the city, state, country. While typing i selected the address shown in picture link #3, and it autofills what is shown in picture link #2.

Does anyone know how to replace the full address with just the number & street after clicking on an address? I used html and jscript from this link here:
https://github.com/solodev/address-auto-complete

Picture Link #1: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EcmCH.jpg

Picture Link #2: https://i.stack.imgur.com/odNTT.jpg

Picture Link #3: https://i.stack.imgur.com/weHIf.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try modifying the `fillInAddress` as follows:

```
function fillInAddress() {
  // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
  var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

  for (var component in componentForm) {
    document.getElementById(component).value = '';
    document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
  }

  // Get each component of the address from the place details
  // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
  var streetAddress = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
    var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
    if (componentForm[addressType]) {

      if (addressType === 'street_number') {
        streetAddress += place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
      } else if (addressType === 'route') {
        if (streetAddress.length) {
          streetAddress += ' ';
        }
        streetAddress += place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
      }

      var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
      document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
      document.getElementById('autocomplete').value = streetAddress;
    }
  }
}
```

[Working jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vd1taLs7/) based off of [the demo](https://jsfiddle.net/solodev/ykajnmkk/).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Glad to hear & happy to help! :)